# How to convert this sql query to pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

```
SELECT A.* FROM df1 A
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM df2)
```

This is the code I'm trying to convert

Comment: did u tried something? please add what have you tried so far..!

Comment: df1.filter(~col('ID').isin(df2.ID))

Comment: This is what I tried, not sure if this is the right way

Comment: Which version of spark are you using?

Comment: I'm using spark version 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [**Spark-2.2+**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19017) supports subqueries, as you can register temp view and execute the same query.

In DataFrameApi for **`NOT IN`** use [**`left_anti`**](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join) join to mimic the same query.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+----+---+
#|name| id|
#+----+---+
#|   a|  1|
#|   c|  3|
#+----+---+

df1.show()
#+----+---+
#|name| id|
#+----+---+
#|   a|  1|
#|   b|  2|
#+----+---+

df.join(df1,'id','left_anti').show()
#+---+----+
#| id|name|
#+---+----+
#|  3|   c|
#+---+----+

#only if you have few id values in df2 then
ids=df1.select("id").rdd.map(lambda x:x.id).collect()

#isin accepts only values not columns from another dataframe
df.filter(~col("id").isin(ids)).show()
#+----+---+
#|name| id|
#+----+---+
#|   c|  3|
#+----+---+
```

If two dataframes having same number of columns then you can use **`exceptAll`** function

```
df.exceptAll(df1).show()
#+----+---+
#|name| id|
#+----+---+
#|   c|  3|
#+----+---+
```

---

For **`in`** subquery use **`left_semi`** join.

```
df.join(df1,'id','left_semi').show()
#+---+----+
#| id|name|
#+---+----+
#|  1|   a|
#+---+----+
```

Comment: Would Left_anti work even if the ID column is not unique?

Comment: If ID not matching then the row will be in the result of left_anti join!